# Customize Android EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, customization

Is there a way that I can customize the android EditText just like the image below? Thanks.

[image: Customize EditText]

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:background="@color/front_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText android:layout_height="35dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText1" android:background="@color/front_white"
        android:hint="Email Address"></EditText>
    <TextView android:layout_height="1dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/dark_gry" />
    <EditText android:layout_height="35dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText2" android:background="@color/front_white"
        android:hint="Re-enter"></EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it is what you are looking for..

Answer (score 0):

I think in your layout you can put 2 edit text 
and a picture 
so you will have a layout that will have background a picture and after to esit box

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Set the background of the Linear/Relative or whatever layout your using to hold the EditTexts to the silver image.

Add the EditText and set the background to transparent in color. Add a text hint with what you want.

Add another image view with the border.

Answer (score 0):

in xml file use this property

> android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_launcher"