# How can I change the apppearance of AutoCompleteTextView in Android

Tags: android, customization, autocompletetextview

I want to change the appearance of AutoCompleteTextView. I mean, want to custom it with my ideas just the part of TextView. How can I do it. Am i suppose to create a complete new class from the base class View or I can extent the functionality of AutoCompleteText.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this

- Extend the `AutoComplete` class
- Use `EditText` class to implement custom `AutoComplete` TextView

you can find more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316214/customize-android-edittext)

**Update**

You can use `OnDraw()` method to perform custom drawings [Example](http://marakana.com/s/post/1036/android_2d_graphics_example)

Comment: I am sorry if didn't elaborate my question but I want to change the shape of edittext in autocomplete class.. I mean some particular shape with filling inside instead of its default appearance of a single line.

Comment: you mean there is onDraw() method of AutoCompleteTextView which i need to override for my customization??

Comment: ooops, sorry i am just a newbie here :) as indicated from by reputation.